# Not getting merge field value of vf email template in apex code

Tags: before-trigger

I am working on trigger in which I am sending a mail(using VF email template) to user when my project status will change to "Approved". Also I need to attach sent mail to the project's object notes and attachment section.

Mail is successfully sent with merge field value now I want all the contents sent in mail into some string in my apex code.

I have tried querying template body but I am not getting merge field value in my string. Also I have tried using 
`getMergedBody()` method which is of class `RenderEmailTemplateBodyResult` and  `Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId, whoId, whatId)` to get merge field value but I am getting salesforce internal server error.

Please provide me the proper solution.

Comment: are you sending email using single email message ?